# Confusion about Selenium and WebDrivers

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, junit, headless-browser

I got into a project which requires a WebGUI to be tested. Selenium is used for this in combination with Jenkins to schedule tasks and run the tests. All of this is handled by one server (Linux).

Regular tests work fine but WebGUI tests fail and I am supposed to make them work. However I'm very confused by the roles of Jenkins' Plugin "Selenium Grid" (is it even neccessary), the JUnit tests inside the project utilizing a selenium libary and the setup of the headless browser required.

What exactly are the roles of the plugin "Selenium Grid" for Jenkins and how does the Selenium libary communicate with a headless browser (Role of WebDrivers?)?
I already know about the Selenium hub and nodes but have no idea how to approach this.

I hope somebody can help me cleaning up my confusion...

Comment: Role of the Driver is to allow your code to communicate with web browser process by sending it requests. IIRC, Selenium Grid is supposed to emulate multiple users at once working with your site, where each "user" does its own thing. This way tests can execute in parallel on several machines.

Comment: Only one machine is supposed to be used. As it is a server, no GUI is available (due to restrictions XVFB cannot be installed) and preferably Firefox and IE should be tested.

Should this machine be a Selenium Hub launching itself as the only Node again? Or can I just use the Selenium libary in Java with a WebDriver?

Answer (score 2):

A **Selenium Grid** can be used to set up a scalable automated browser environment. It is often used for automated GUI testing. It consists of a Hub and one or more Nodes.

A **Selenium Hub** should be started and the resulting URL should be stored.

Then a desired number of **Selenium Nodes** should be started with a reference to the Url of the Hub. The nodes will register themselves to the Hub.

Then you could use [Selenium Java](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java) to create a [RemoteWebDriver](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Remote_RemoteWebDriver.htm) instance, optionally specifying the url of the Selenium Hub. This webdriver is just a Java API, the actual work will be done in the Selenium Node environment(s).

You can use the Java API to implement your desired operations on the WebDriver instance. When running, the code will delegate all calls to the running Selenium environment.

There are multiple ways to actually start the hub and nodes. A Jenkins Plugin could do it, you could use [Docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/selenium/), a local process, or many more. I'd advise to not bind your setup directly to Jenkins unless you are certain that you will never switch.

The [Jenkins Selenium Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Selenium+Plugin) specifies the URL that you should create a WebDriver with:

```
new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://jenkins.mydomain:4444/wd/hub"), capability);
```

Where `jenkins.mydomain` will probably be the IP of your Linux server. Just above it is a line that says that it "also" accepts external nodes. I am not familiar with the plugin, so I dont know whether this means that it sets up one or more nodes itself by default.

Comment: Thanks for this clarification.
So Selenium Grid (the Jenkins Plugin) says, it turns Jenkins into a hub to which nodes can connect to. Now I can use a WebDriver Implementation , give it the URL+Port of my Selenium Hub and use the WebDriver class to test my Website?

It confused me because HUB and Node would be the same machine, which seemed like the way it shouldn't be.

Comment: @GxTruth I've added some more information specifically regarding the Jenkins plugin.

Answer (score 1):

taken from the following website. 
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Selenium+Plugin

This plugin sets up Selenium Grid in the following way

- On master, Selenium Grid Hub is started on port 4444, unless configured otherwise in Jenkins global configurations. This is where all your tests should connect to.
- For each slave, necessary binaries are copied and Selenium RCs are started.
- RCs and the Selenium Grid Hub are hooked up together automatically.

Now the question is do you need this?

This is upto the requirement of the project. You just need to ask this question to yourself

- do you need to run tests in parallel (to cutdown time or for browser compatibility testing), either now or in near future.

Comment: There are only a few tests for WebGUI, so probably no parallel testing is required. However, Firefox and Internet Explorer are supposed to be supported, so a test is neccessary.
However, only one machine should be involved, so I don't have a dozen machines running Selenium nodes with different browsers/OSes. Can I use different WebDriver (different Modes?) to simulate this?

Comment: yes you can. just remove the plugin and bind the execution to some node.

Comment: One more question. The WebDrivers seem to use headless browsers which require the actual browser as an external application. Is this the case or does Selenium implement a headless browser without the need for an external tool?

Comment: what do you mean by headless browser, chrome in headless or phantomjs driver? you should read more about automation online and how selenium actually works.